# Is continuous map from covering space to itself homeomorphism assumed both cover and base path-connected and $pf=p$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In my topology assignment I came across the following problem:

> True or false? Let $E$ and $X$ be path-connected. For every covering map $p:E\rightarrow X$ and continuous map $f:E\rightarrow E$ such that $pf=p$ holds $f$ is homeomorphism.

I couldn't think of any counterexample, so my guess is that assertion is true. Since $X$ is not locally path-connected, I cannot apply lifting theorem to obtain $f$ and its inverse, so I guess I should manually prove properties of homeomorphism on $f$, using path lifting theorem several times.

Recently I had to deal with the operation of a fundamental group operation on a set $p^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in X$ such that $p^{-1}(x)\times \pi_1(X,x)\rightarrow \pi_1(X, x): [w]\cdot e=w(1)$, that is each point in $E$ maps to the endpoint of a unique lift of the path $w$ (similar to the one in Hatcher). I played around a little trying to prove injection / surjection property of $f$, but didn't got far. The only thing I proved is that $f([w]\cdot e) = [w]\cdot f(e)$ but nothing more.

So I ask what would be an adequate approach to solve this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought topologist's comb is path connected but not locally path connected.

Comment: I guess [spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146) agrees with me on that.

Comment: Never mind, my mistake

Comment: Also, thanks for spacebook.  Never again will I look so silly

Comment: I don't understand the quantifiers. You've fixed E and X but are then taking a universal quantifier over $p$. What if there are no covering maps between E and X?

Comment: This is how it's written on my paper. Ok, I reread this and this really sounds a bit misleading. Following was meant: Let $p$ and $f$ be as given above and $pf = p$. Then $f$ is a homeo.

Comment: This is simply not true. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Here's a hint for showing that $f$ is a local homeomorphism: The condition $pf=p$ implies that points in $e$ are carried to points in the fiber $p^{-1}(p(e))$. 
We can find neighborhoods $U$ of $e$ and $W$ of $f(e)$ such that $p$ restricts to a homeomorphism on each neighborhood and $f(U) \subset W$. See if you can use this to show that $f$ in fact carries $U$ homeomorphically into a subset of $W$.

**Hint 2:** [Courtesy of the OP's own suggestion in the comments below.] For both injectivity and surjectivity: The action of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ on $p^{-1}(x_0)$ can be shown to satisfy $f(e) \cdot [\gamma]=f(e \cdot [\gamma])$. Playing around with this fact and a couple well-chosen paths between points in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ will give both injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: Concerning bijectivity: in my another [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852951/) where you also engaged in discussion I have defined an action of the fundamental group on $E$ (path (homotopy class) in $X$ maps each point in $E$ to the endpoint of the unique lifted path) and proved that $f(e\cdot [w]) = f(e) \cdot[w]$, where $f$ is a continuous map on $E$ having $pf=p$ and $e\cdot[w]$ is aforementioned action.

Comment: In order to prove surjectivity, let $e\in E$. Pick any other $e_1 \in E$ and let $f(e_1)=e_2$. Now let $w$ be the path between $e_2$ and $e$ (exists, since $E$ path-connected). Then $e = e_2\cdot[w] = f(e_1)\cdot[w] = f(e_1 \cdot [w]) = f(e_2)$. So $f$ is surjective, and bijective as it maps into itself. Does this look sound?

Comment: @haemhweg: Nice thinking, but it doesn't quite work because $w$ needs to be a path between two elements of the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$ in order for $[p\circ w]$ to make sense as an element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. Try and see if you can rework that part of the proof.

Comment: Secondly, a surjective map from a space to itself isn't necessarily bijective -- even if the map is a local homeomorphism. That said, your style of argument *does* give you injectivity. Suppose $f(e)=f(e')$. Like you said, there's a path $w: [0,1]\to E$ with $w(0)=e,w(1)=e'$. Then play with the fact that $f(e) \cdot [p\circ w]=f(e\cdot [p\circ w])$.

Comment: (Since the surjectivity part of your argument can be tweaked to work, I have modified my answer to include this new hint for future readers. I've credited you with the second hint, so feel free to ask me to change it, if necessary.)

Comment: Thank you, nice work. Since the most work was done, I'll accept your answer. Only detail I wanted to tweak is that in my second comment here equality $f(e_1\cdot[w])=f(e_2)$ doesn't hold, but this doesn't affect surjectivity I was about to prove anyway.

Comment: @Kyle Your smart answer is unfortunately wrong: your recipe to show infectivity does not work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for the OP, their topology assignment is wrong, even with the stronger hypothesis of $E$ and $X$ being connected and locally path connected.

There is a counter example for this in the paper of Lima called **Fundamental Groups and Covering Spaces** on page 179, example 7.20.

The mechanics of this counterexample is clearly described also in this MO question
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80105/why-do-the-definition-of-deck-transformations-requires-homeomorphism